# Having to replace tires

Tags: tires, kia

I have a 2011 Kia Sorento.  I've had it since March, 2010, so almost three years.  In that time, I've had to replace each of the tires at least once, if not twice.  Two months ago I had to replace the two front tires.  I checked with two car repair places at the time, and they came up with roughly the same price and the same suggestion.  I ended up choosing the one that I had gone to before.

So about a week ago, I started to feel that the car was learning forward a little.  I'm super sensitive though, so I decided to wait and see if the tire light came on.  Well, it did come on last night, and it feels like there might be another problem with both of the two new front tires.  I called the place that I brought my car to two months ago and they are going to have a look at it on Monday, so I don't know the verdict as of yet.  I'm assuming that the warranty for the tires should still be in place since I've had them for such a short time.

My question is, could there be something else on my car that is causing my front tires to have issues?

Comment: Are you replacing the tires because of leaks/punctures or are they wearing unevenly/prematurely

Answer (score 2):

By tire light, do you mean tire pressure light? If so, I wouldn't worry - you should as a matter of course be checking your tire pressures every week.

If you think the tires are deflating much faster than they should, you should look at:

- have the tires been seated correctly
- are the rims clean and free from corrosion
- are the rims bashed or chipped
- is the valve sealed correctly
- are the correct tires on the rim

Any of these can cause loss of pressure.